# Enabling Amazon EC2 always running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running heroku jobs on Amazon EC2 `heroku rake jobs:work`.For this I log in to terminal using .pem file and now when I close the terminal this jobs:work also stops , How can I enable Amazon EC2 to always run this.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has noting to do with EC2. Any active job which is run via a ssh terminal will get terminated when you exit the ssh session.

To Avoid this, use [screen](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen)

The package `screen` is available in default package repo for ubuntu and RPM based distros.

1. Create a screen session
2. Attach to the screen session you created in step 1
3. Run the command you want into the screen session
4. exit the screen session when you have to exit. The job will continue inside the sreen session whihc is still active
5. Later whenever you want to connect to see the job status, re-attach the screen session and you will find that your job is active and running.

This question was more suited to superuser instead of stack-overflow. I leave it as a home work for you to figure out the exact screen commands to accomplish above points.

Comment: Hey , thanks for the answer i figure it out using nohup command.